RestAPI should accept date and DateTime
My REST API has two params, 'from' and 'to' - which should accept either Date or DateTime. sometimes they might be interested to pass only Date, in that case we consider Time is added as begining of the day.
I tried with LocalDateTime as a RequestParameter, but it throws error if we pass only Date but not time.
Then I thought I take as String and then convert based on the value. Want to know is there any other better solutions.
@GetMapping("/test/entity")
    private ResponseEntity<Test.Result> invoke(
            @RequestParam(name = "from", required = false) String from,
            @RequestParam(name = "to", required = false) String to)
            {
                LocalDateTime d1 = toLocalDateTime(from);
                LocalDateTime d2 = toLocalDateTime(to);
            }


      public static LocalDateTime toLocalDateTime(String date)
      {
        final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(date))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (date.length() <= 10)
        {
            LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);
            return ld.atStartOfDay();
        }
        return LocalDateTime.parse(date);
      }

If someone is -ve ranking, I want to know why they do that - its a big puzzle(:-()) for me.

You can use a custom @RequestParam binding approach. Converter<String, LocalDateTime> can be used to handle conversion based on the input. and then using @Configuration to register the converter so that Spring automatically applies it.

Create a Custom Converter
@Component
public class StringToLocalDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

  private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
  private static final DateTimeFormatter DATETIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;

  @Override
  public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
    if (source == null || source.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      // Try parsing as Date
      LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(source, DATE_FORMAT);
      return date.atStartOfDay();
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
      // Try parsing as DateTime
      return LocalDateTime.parse(source, DATETIME_FORMAT);
    }
  }
}


Register the Converter
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new StringToLocalDateTimeConverter());
  }
}


Update Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

  @GetMapping("/entity")
  public ResponseEntity<String> invoke(
        @RequestParam(name = "from", required = false) LocalDateTime from,
        @RequestParam(name = "to", required = false) LocalDateTime to) {

    // 'from' and 'to' will automatically be converted to LocalDateTime
    return ResponseEntity.ok("From: " + from + ", To: " + to);
   }
}




I liked this approach even though I stick to my approach bec of simplicity. Thank you.
